# Checking the logic using if statement in expect

Tags: expect

I have a scenario where i will connect to a remote machine and execute a command (priorietery) in expect which  it gives an ouput. I am checking the exact pattern and if it is success i need to open a file which is created by the above command which got executed.

I need to go the specififed directory and open the file and parse the same for which i am using expect with tcl and the code is mentioned below

```
#!/home/pub/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 172.16.67.213 23 
expect "login name:"
send "administrator\r"
expect "password:"
send "Administrator1@\r"
expect "Windows NT Domain:"
send "\r"    
expect "C:\WINNT\Profiles\Administrator>"
send "\r"
expect "C:\WINNT\Profiles\Administrator>"
send "x -j Y -a run -d\r"
sleep 60
expect "ZZ"

****if {[string match *Z* $expect_out(buffer)]} {
        send "dir";} else {
    puts "Script failed";
    }****
```

Here the script is executing till the string match and when success the next command send "dir" is not executed.

If i replace the logic as below i am getting the echo statement but instaed if i want to execute some other command after if it is not succeeded.

```
**if {[string match *Z* $expect_out(buffer)]} {
        puts "Script passed";} else {
    puts "Script failed";
    }**
```

I hope the problem is clear and i am trying all the ways but not succeeded..

Thanks in advance,
Kamesh.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the `dir` together with newline would fire the command:

```
send "dir\n"
```

The command now gets executed but the output may not be seen (printed by script to stdout) until subsequent expect match. To flush it immediately (say for script debugging) use: `set timeout 1; expect; expect *`.